# How to expand $x/\sin x$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Please help me, I have no idea how to solve this.

I know the expansion of $\sin x$ but am not sure if it will apply for $1/\sin x$.

Comment: The result may not look good...

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac x{\sin x}~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{b_n}\cdot x^{2n},~$ where $a_n$ forms the sequence described [here](http://oeis.org/A036280), and $b_n$ is the one found [here](http://oeis.org/A036281).